# Set div width that is equal half of window with minus 25px using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to subtract `25px` or any number of `px` from two `divs` that have width set to **half of window width**

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/vzwa2fjL/8/

Here is what i got  so far with JS

```
$(window).resize(setHeightAndWidth);
$(document).ready(setHeightAndWidth);

function setHeightAndWidth() {
    var halfWidth = $('.left, .right').width($(window).width() / 2);

    $('.section').height($(window).height());
    halfWidth;
}
```

I just need to do `halfWidth - 25px;` but i am not sure how.

Comment: ($(window).width() / 2) - 25   .. is that what you looking for??

Comment: `var halfWidth = $('.left, .right').width(($(window).width() / 2)-(25));` ?

Comment: Yep, i was using `-25px` instead of `-25`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) with relative viewport width.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vzwa2fjL/10/)

```
.left, .right {
    ....
    width: calc(50vw - 25px);
}
```

[**Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)

---

As `calc` is not *reliable* to use across mobile browsers, jQuery can be used.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vzwa2fjL/13/)

```
$('.left, .right').width($(window).width() / 2 - 25);
```

Also,

```
$('.section').height($(window).height());
```

is not necessary when the same can be done in CSS.

```
.section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `calc()` considering its support.

Comment: @RayonDabre It's supported by Most of the _modern_ browsers, I've also included browser compatibility link.

Comment: It has given me lots of pain in Android 2.3. :(